# cassandra how to organized value in sstable

Tags: cassandra

I am curios that cassandra how to organized value of row in sstable.
Does it storage column key every row?

e.g.

```
table  
c1 int primary key,  
c2 int,  
c3 int,  

insert into table(c1,c2,c3) values(1,2,3)
```

how does cassandra to storage it?
like this:
c1 -> 2,3

or like this:
c1 -> c2:2,c3:3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It largely depends on the version of Cassandra you are using as the way Cassandra organizes data changes between C* 2.2 and C* 3.0.  You can read about those changes [here](https://www.datastax.com/2015/12/storage-engine-30).  Before C* 3.0, SSTables were composed of partition keys and their cells; in 3.0 SSTables are composed of partitions and their rows (which contain cells).

The best way to find out how data is organized is to use a tool like [`sstabledump`](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/tools/ToolsSSTabledump.html) (C* 3.0+) or [`sstable2json`](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsSSTable2JsonNew.html) to observe how data is organized on disk after performing some updates and flushing to disk.

[The following article](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/debugging-sstables-in-3-0-with-sstabledump) gives an overview of how to use sstabledump.

For your proposed schema and insert, here's an example of how things appear:

```js
[
  {
    "partition" : {
      "key" : [ "1" ],
      "position" : 0
    },
    "rows" : [
      {
        "type" : "row",
        "position" : 32,
        "liveness_info" : { "tstamp" : "2018-09-06T00:03:38.558182Z" },
        "cells" : [
          { "name" : "c2", "value" : 2 },
          { "name" : "c3", "value" : 3 }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

As you can see, data is organized by partition, and then within a partition there are rows.  Within each row are cells, with each cell representing a column value.

There is also additional metadata that can be present at the partition, row and cell level.  The C* 3 storage engine also optimizes space by not storing the names of each column in every cell (where C* 2 did).